# Python import function to class

Tags: python, class, import, module

Following structure:

- FolderA

  - Utils.py
- FolderB

  - MyClass.py
- start.py

Utils.py:

```
def help(txt):
  return txt + ' hi'
```

MyClass.py:

```
from FolderA import Utils

Class MyClass(object):
def TestMe():
  Utils.help('me')
```

All is started from start.py.
This gives my an NameError because `Utils` is not defined.

If i change the import statement to `from FolderA.Utils import help`
and the calling line in TestMe to `help('me')`, i get also a NameError because help is not defined.
If i put the import INTO the method TestMe, it works fine.

```
Class MyClass(object):
def TestMe():
  from FolderA import Utils
  Utils.help('me')
```

WHY won't the general import at the top of the file work?

Comment: You need the __init__.Py file check the python documentation  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Please post actual code. None of this will run at all because the keyword is `class`, not `Class`. And even if that's corrected, you wouldn't get a NameError in either of those: you should also post the real error and the full traceback.

Comment: Could you paste the full traceback which will be easier to comprehend your problem.

Comment: As mentioned, create a __init__.py in folderX from which you would like to import some modules from.
 
And sometimes, import on top not working could be due to a circular dependencies in your imports

Answer (score 0):

You need a blank `__init__.py` file in your directory to let it be imported as a package. Like so...

```
Folder A
 - Utils.py
 - __init__.py
FolderB
 - MyClass.py
 - __init__.py
start.py
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention the __init__.pys. But they are there, otherwise the import IN the method would not worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i forgot to mention the **init**.py files in each of the folders.
That was not the problem, otherwise the import IN the function would not have worked out.

The problem is much nicer.

I could not post the original code, cause it was to complicated and to much. So i made up the example you see above. The example works without problem. So i tried a bit more and figured the problem out.

I start the python script from an other application. The application therefore starts a python console and holds this instance til the application dies. If i started the python code via the application once, changed some code in python and restarted the python code via the application a second time, i cannot see any difference, cause the python code is cached by the python console. So i would have to close the application and restart it, each time i make changes in the pys. Therefore i implemented a reload mechanism. This explicitly removes and restarts all modules i give in. (parameter=modules).
This reloader is called in the start.py and so i have to import all modules i need and use lateron in the start.py. The reloader then deletes them from cache (del sys.modules[name]) and reloads the module. 
And that is the problem.
By this mechanism python does the following.

- It loads all imports subsequently.
- main() is started.
- main() calls the reloader.
- The reloader removes all modules from its cache.

So the modules are imported and no error is seen at build time, but at runtime the imports are gone and so nothing was defined. 
By moving the import away from the top of the file to the using method, the import was redone, when calling the method and therefore it worked again.

I dont know if the error was caused by the double import (one in the start.py and one in the py that really needs the import) or the reload mechanism, but my solution now works.

Solution:
I dont import the moduls in the start.py. I just give the reloader the names of the modules and it now only removes them from sys.modules. I dont do a reimport, this is only done by the following pys.